# Does Blender not support the PSB format when Image texturing

Tags: texturing, image, file-format

A quick question. I'm currently editing textures, and the file has become so large that it's saved as a PSB document instead of PSD. When I try to input it into the image texture node in Blender, it doesn't seem to work. Does Blender not support the PSB format?

Answer (score 2):

.PSD and .PSB are not fully supported. They are not even listed in [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/image_formats.html#supported-graphics-formats). But they do work. You can import both formats. Since they are not officially supported, you get what you get though and some functionality will not work.

Try simply dragging the files to some material nodes to see if they work quickly. A file with some basic stuff in it seems to work with both PSD and PSB formats with Blender 4.0.2 when I test it on Windows.

Comment: Thanks! I tried before posting here and I got pinkish texture, so that's why I was wondering if the PSB format wasn't supported. But that's weird that it seems to work for you but not me. Hmm...

Comment: That is what I would expect - it will work in some cases and in some cases it will not. It probably depends on what you have in the .PSB file and what Photoshop features it uses. I would expect smart objects and features related to them might not work, video layers and stuff like that. Any fancy features basically might be problematic. Different Photoshop versions might play a role here as well. I used version 24 to test, but I only painted some color and added hue adjust layer... Seemed to work with that.